# React unable to import component -- module not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I just started with React.js and I am unable to import component.

I have this structure as followed by [this tutorial (YouTube link)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wK4gHoOh1g&list=PL55RiY5tL51oyA8euSROLjMFZbXaV7skS&index=5) :

```
-- src
----| index.html
----| app
------| index.js
------| components
--------| MyCompontent.js
```

This is my `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import { MyCompontent } from "./components/MyCompontent";

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <h1>Foo</h1>
              <MyCompontent/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

render(<App />, window.document.getElementById('app'));
```

This is `MyComponent.js`:

```
import React from "react";

export class MyCompontent extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div>MyCompontent</div>
    );
  }
}
```

I am using [this webpack file (GitHub link)](https://github.com/mschwarzmueller/reactjs-basics/blob/03-multiple-components/webpack.config.js).

However, when I run this, my module fails to load.

I get this error in the browser console:

> Error: Cannot find module "./components/MyCompontent"

```
[WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.  bundle.js:631:11
[WDS] Errors while compiling.  bundle.js:631:11
./src/app/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./components/MyCompontent in /home/kuno/code/react-hoteli/src/app
resolve file
  /home/kuno/code/react-hoteli/src/app/components/MyCompontent doesn't exist
  /home/kuno/code/react-hoteli/src/app/components/MyCompontent.webpack.js doesn't exist
  /home/kuno/code/react-hoteli/src/app/components/MyCompontent.web.js doesn't exist
  /home/kuno/code/react-hoteli/src/app/components/MyCompontent.js doesn't exist
  /home/kuno/code/react-hoteli/src/app/components/MyCompontent.json doesn't exist
resolve directory
  /home/kuno/code/react-hoteli/src/app/components/MyCompontent/package.json doesn't exist (directory description file)
  /home/kuno/code/react-hoteli/src/app/components/MyCompontent doesn't exist (directory default file)
[/home/kuno/code/react-hoteli/src/app/components/MyCompontent]
[/home/kuno/code/react-hoteli/src/app/components/MyCompontent.webpack.js]
[/home/kuno/code/react-hoteli/src/app/components/MyCompontent.web.js]
[/home/kuno/code/react-hoteli/src/app/components/MyCompontent.js]
[/home/kuno/code/react-hoteli/src/app/components/MyCompontent.json]
 @ ./src/app/index.js 11:20-56  bundle.js:669:5
```

Can't figure out what went wrong here.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have a typo in your import. You're requesting `MyCompontent`. Change to:

```
import MyComponent from "./components/MyComponent";
```

And all typos as well.

Comment: You have a typo, might be relevant: `MyCompontent` instead of `MyComponent`

Comment: Yes that was a typo. I am sorry.

Comment: Also make sure to npm start after the typo correction if the problem exists.

Comment: This may or may not be relevant for this situation but also be mindful of case in your directory paths.  I had a situation where my local directories were lower case, but in prod they were upper.  I had to completely wipe away my local structure and clone from prod to fix it, otherwise I was going to spend a lot of time refactoring directory names.

Answer (score 53):

For anyone coming here ***without*** a typo, and is using Webpack, be sure to check for a clause like this:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: [".jsx", ".js"]
},
```

in your **webpack.config.js**.

This tells your transpiler to resolve statements like:

```
import Setup from './components/Setup'
```

to

```
import Setup from './components/Setup.jsx'
```

This way you don't need the extension.

Comment: this helped . I missed a dot in the extension type like extensions: ["jsx", ".js"] instead of extensions: [".jsx", ".js"]

Comment: After doing this I had to fully rerun webpack for the changes to apply, `--watch` did not catch them.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to import MyCompontent from "./components/MyCompontent.js"

like this

```
import MyCompontent from "./components/MyCompontent.js";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have written that the filename is MyComponent.js.

Thus, your import should look like

```
import { MyCompontent } from './components/MyComponent.js'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me was that import line was not generated correctly. I have this scenario:

```
--src
----elements
-----myCustomText.tsx
```

this is myCustomText.tsx file:

```
export interface Props {
  text: string;
}

const MyCustomText = ({ text }: Props) => (
  <Text>{text}</Text>
);

export default MyCustomText
```

And the generated import was this:

```
import MyCustomText from '../../elements/MyCustomText';
```

and I changed it to this:

```
import MyCustomText from '../../elements/myCustomText'
```

I don't know why the generated import line was generated automatically wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I found myself here without a typo and without a webpack issue.

The solution for me was to [restart the typescript](https://tinytip.co/tips/vscode-restart-ts/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20restart%20the%20server,TypeScript%3A%20Restart%20TS%20server%22.) server via VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue, no type or webpack config issues.

What fixed it was changing the import from relative to the app root directory to relative to the file:

```
import MyComponent from "src/components/MyComponent";
```

to

```
import MyComponent from "../components/MyComponent";
```

If you're getting this from Visual Studio Code auto-importing via the shortest route, you can change it so it imports **relatively**. By going here:

menu *File → Preferences → Settings → User Settings*,

```
"typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "relative"
```

Answer (score 1):

export 'Component' (imported as 'Component') was not found in 'react'

if you find your self stuck with this error simply go to mini-create-react-context, and go to cjs, and go to index.js and add "React" example: you will find this (Component) solution (React.Component) only if you extends to React.Component in you pages

Note: I have only used this on VS Code