# React import component from another folder issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I did add the folder structure so you could see.

How am I able to import image component into the card component ? Doesn't matter what path I try I get this error

```
./src/Components/Card/Card.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../../Components/Image' in 
'/Users/user/project/projecttest/src/Components/Card'


import React from 'react'
import styled, {ThemeProvider, css } from 'styled-components'
import Image from '../../Components/Image'
```

[image]

Comment: You are using it in card.js right

Comment: @Kiwimoisi import like this './src/Components/Card/Card'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React unable to import component -- module not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41322867/react-unable-to-import-component-module-not-found)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, I see you importing: `import Image from '../../Components/Image'`. This mean you importing `index` of `Image folder`.

But in your code, you defining `Image.js` not `index.js`.
So, you have to import like this:

```
import Image from '../Image/Image'
```

Or, you can rename file `Image.js` to `index.js` to shorten the code when import:

```
// rename Image.js to index.js
// then, import file:
import Image from '../Image'
```

Answer (score 7):

You should write Image at the end or change filename to index.js

```
import Image from '../../Components/Image/Image'
```

Comment: Exactly: ```import Image from '../Image/Image'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try absolute imports in react. create a .env file in your root directory. contents of the file

NODE_PATH=src

Comment: can you explain a little more.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But now we can use the file `jsconfig.json`. Take a look [Discussion on: Configuring absolute paths in React for Web without ejecting](https://dev.to/averyfreeman/comment/1214j) and [CRA - Absolute Imports](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/#absolute-imports)

Answer (score 0):

@Jikun L answer is correct. I'm wondering why is it not in image format.

Perhaps Change the Folder Structure to this:

Components

-- Card

-- -- > index.js

-- -- > styles.js

-- Image

-- -- > xxx.png

-- -- > package.json

Package.json:

```
{
    "name": "@image"
}
```

In Card (index.js)

```
  <Image
    source={require("@images/xxx.png")}
  />
```