# How do I solve the error "Module not found: Can't resolve './undraw_Upload_image_re_svxx' in 'D:\libref\src'"?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm using an illustration in a React project, which is stored in `/src`, along with `App.js`. I imported it like this:

```js
import Illustration from "./undraw_Upload_image_re_svxx";
...
function App() {
  ...
  return (
    ...
    <img src={Illustration}/>
  )
}
```

However, I got this error: `Module not found: Can't resolve './undraw_Upload_image_re_svxx' in 'D:\libref\src'`. I can just copy the SVG into the code, but it's not very aesthetic. How can I solve this?

Comment: does you custom module file have an extension like .js or .jsx? please take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41322867/react-unable-to-import-component-module-not-found

Answer (score 1):

In React projects built with CRA, common extensions like .js and .jsx gets resolved by webpack config, so while importing those files you can drop the extension part. But here, since you are trying to import a svg file you will have to include the extension part as well in the import statement.

```
import Illustration from "./undraw_Upload_image_re_svxx.svg";
```