# React - Error while auto CI/CD from github actions to firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, github, github-actions, firebase-hosting

[This is the error i got from github actions while it was performing auto CI/CD to firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMT73.png)

[This is the workflow file in github actions for this project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQo87.png)

Now, when pushing changes to github, the github actions should perform CI/CD

But i am getting a error while running npm i ci && npm i build

Note: Clean install is done, and i am stuck at building

Here is the error :
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app/routes/AppRoutes' in '/home/runner/work/forms-react-nestjs/forms-react-nestjs/forms/src'

I have never worked on react enough to to face this issue before

And i am also assuming since i am changing the working-directory to ./forms before running npm ci && npm run build, this issue is being shown

Edit: I have forgot to mention , that the AppRoutes is actually AppRoutes.tsx (have a export of createRouter from react-router-dom)

Most importantly,
When im building same thing in local machine and manually deploying in firebase hosting,
every thing is PERRRRPect

Need some assistance

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "forms",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/icons": "^2.1.0",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.8.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.8",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.55",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "formik": "^2.4.3",
    "framer-motion": "^6.5.1",
    "immer": "^10.0.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^3.11.0",
    "react-player": "^2.12.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.15.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "yup": "^1.2.0",
    "zustand": "^4.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd -f .env.development react-scripts start",
    "build": "env-cmd -f .env.production react-scripts build",
    "test": "env-cmd react-scripts test"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your package.json?  It's unclear if you're using webpack, CRA, or another bundler.  In the meantime, you may also want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41322867/react-unable-to-import-component-module-not-found

Comment: Hey i have just edited this question to add package.json as well

please go through it

Comment: Perfect!  Looks like you're using CRA (Create React App); I'm assuming you haven't ejected it yet?  If you have, can you post the config files (unless you haven't edited any of it after ejection).  Looks like you're also using Typescript.  Can you post the tsconfig.json?  It will specify how you're handling module resolution, which may not be configured correctly.

Comment: Hey i have added tsconfig.json as well, plase check it out
(also i have heard before, that people don't use CRA for some reasons)

Comment: I do have a angular app with moduleResolution:"node" that had auto CI/CD github workflow and it was working fine

I have to mention something. that AppRoutes is not .ts, its .tsx

Comment: Hmm, can't see any issues so far.  Your path seems a bit off... is your root repo (where the tsconfig.json is located) `/forms` or `/forms-react-nestjs`?  If `/forms-react-nestjs`, then you probably need to move your `src` one level down so it can be picked up by the tsconfig.  You also have two levels of `/forms-react-nestjs` in your path.  Your CI/CD may be picking up on the one higher up, depending on where you initialized git.  Finally, it's not clear what's importing `./app/routes/AppRoutes`.  Do you have a `index.ts` or `index.js` in `src` or just a `index.tsx`?  Can I see the import?

Comment: Regarding not using CRA anymore, that is correct, the community isn't very happy with CRA (see some of the larger issues on its issue board for the discussion: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues) and it's assumed to be in maintenance mode.  React has an updated list of recommendations: https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project.  I would also look into Vite.js if I were you.